# Measuring latency of requests in a Netty server

Tags: java, netty

I want to measure the latency of requests on the server side of a Netty HTTP server. I want to capture the time spent by requests in the server since the requests are received at the server until the reply is sent out the server. I want this to include even the time requests spend waiting for resources (Ex. Threads) as well. Basically, capture the latency of requests on the server as much as possible.

I use Dropwizard metrics and started the timer at the overridden `initChannel(SocketChannel ch)` method and stopped it after `ctx.flush()` at the overridden `channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx)` method.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You usually would start it in `channelRead(...)` when the first byte for a request was received and would stop it in the last `ChannelFutureListener` that belongs the response.